# Get current URL from active tab chrome vb net?

Tags: vb.net

I have search on google with keyword same as this question title. 
Some code not work or complicated explanation, even in stackoverflow link. 
I found one link work [here](http://www.bluelightdev.com/get-list-open-chrome-tabs).
But that code result is page title, not url.
How to make this code below to retrieve current url active tab on chrome?
here the code,

```
'//Grab all the Chrome processes
Dim chrome() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")

'//Exit if chrome isn't running
If chrome.Length <= 0 Then Exit Sub

For Each chromeProcess As Process In chrome

'//If the chrome process doesn't have a window handle then ignore it
If chromeProcess.MainWindowHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then

    '//To find the tabs we first need to locate something reliable - the 'New Tab' button
    Dim rootElement As AutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chromeProcess.MainWindowHandle)
    Dim condNewTab As Condition = New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "New Tab")
    Dim elemNewTab As AutomationElement = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, condNewTab)

    '//Get the tabstrip by getting the parent of the 'new tab' button
    Dim tWalker As TreeWalker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker
    Dim elemTabStrip As AutomationElement = tWalker.GetParent(elemNewTab)

    '//Loop through all the tabs and get the names which is the page title
    Dim tabItemCondition As Condition = New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem)
    For Each tabItem As AutomationElement In elemTabStrip.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, tabItemCondition)
        Debug.WriteLine(tabItem.Current.Name)
    Next

End If
Next
```

Comment: Have you tried using Awesomium (http://www.awesomium.com/#download)?   There is more information on this here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534843/google-chrome-control-for-net?lq=1

Comment: Not yet, but I read some topic, it like to make web browser on Vb net, what i need is to capture current url in chrome. Can u give me specific link?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, From another forum,

```
Imports System.Windows.Automation

Module GoogleChrome
Private Const ChromeProcess As [String] = "chrome"
Private Const AddressCtl As [String] = "Address and search bar"

Public Function GetChromeActiveWindowUrl() As [String]
    Dim procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(ChromeProcess)

    If (procs.Length = 0) Then
        Return [String].Empty
    End If

    Return procs _
    .Where(Function(p) p.MainWindowHandle <> IntPtr.Zero) _
    .Select(Function(s) GetUrlControl(s)) _
    .Where(Function(p) p IsNot Nothing) _
    .Select(Function(s) GetValuePattern(s)) _
    .Where(Function(p) p.Item2.Length > 0) _
    .Select(Function(s) GetValuePatternUrl(s)) _
    .FirstOrDefault

End Function

Private Function GetUrlControl( _
    proses As Process) _
    As AutomationElement

    Dim propCondition = _
        New PropertyCondition( _
        AutomationElement.NameProperty, _
        AddressCtl)
    Return AutomationElement _
        .FromHandle(proses.MainWindowHandle) _
        .FindFirst( _
            TreeScope.Descendants, _
            propCondition)

End Function

Private Function GetValuePatternUrl( _
    element As Tuple(Of  _
    AutomationElement, AutomationPattern())) As [String]

    Dim ap = element.Item2(0)
    Dim ovp = element.Item1.GetCurrentPattern(ap)
    Dim vp = CType(ovp, ValuePattern)

    Return vp.Current.Value
End Function

Private Function GetValuePattern( _
    element As AutomationElement) _
As Tuple(Of  _
          AutomationElement,  _
          AutomationPattern())

    Return New Tuple(Of  _
          AutomationElement,  _
          AutomationPattern())( _
          element, _
          element.GetSupportedPatterns())
End Function



End Module
```

Comment: "Address and search bar" as control name only works on English language PCs.

Comment: Don't work - App hangs in GetUrlControl() -> App frozen

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **.Net framework 2.0** it works for Google Chrome 55 And Firefox. Send the process name to the method ("CHROME" or "FIREFOX"). Also, you must import UIAutomationClient.dll. I hope it helps someone.

```
private string GetBrowserUrlActivaChromeFirefox(string process)
    {
        Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName(process);
        foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome)
        {
            if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                continue;


            UIAutomationClient.CUIAutomation element = new UIAutomationClient.CUIAutomation();
            UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement root = element.ElementFromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle);

            if (element == null)
                return "";

            UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition condition1 = element.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_ProcessIdPropertyId, chrome.Id);
            UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition condition2 = element.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_IsControlElementPropertyId, true);
            UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition condition3 = element.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_IsContentElementPropertyId, true);
            UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition condition4 = element.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, UIAutomationClient.UIA_ControlTypeIds.UIA_EditControlTypeId);

            UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition[] conditions = new UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition[4];

            conditions[0] = condition1;
            conditions[1] = condition2;
            conditions[2] = condition3;
            conditions[3] = condition4;

            UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition andCondition = element.CreateAndConditionFromArray(conditions);

            UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement elementx = root.FindFirst(UIAutomationClient.TreeScope.TreeScope_Descendants, andCondition);

            return ((UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationValuePattern)elementx.GetCurrentPattern(UIAutomationClient.UIA_PatternIds.UIA_ValuePatternId)).CurrentValue.ToString();

        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This C# code works for me on non-English browsers:

```
// Check for Chrome
if (processName.Equals("chrome"))
{
    Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
    foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome)
    {
        // the chrome process must have a window
        if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            continue;

        try
        {
            CUIAutomation _automation = new CUIAutomation();
            var appElement = _automation.ElementFromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle);

            IUIAutomationCondition[] conditionArray = new IUIAutomationCondition[3];
            conditionArray[0] = _automation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_ProcessIdPropertyId, chrome.Id);
            conditionArray[1] = _automation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_NamePropertyId, "Google Chrome");
            conditionArray[2] = _automation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, UIA_ControlTypeIds.UIA_PaneControlTypeId);
            IUIAutomationCondition conditions = _automation.CreateAndConditionFromArray(conditionArray);
            IUIAutomationElement frameElement = appElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.TreeScope_Subtree, conditions);
            if (frameElement != null)
            {
                conditionArray = new IUIAutomationCondition[2];
                conditionArray[0] = _automation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_ProcessIdPropertyId, chrome.Id);
                conditionArray[1] = _automation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_PropertyIds.UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, UIA_ControlTypeIds.UIA_EditControlTypeId);
                conditions = _automation.CreateAndConditionFromArray(conditionArray);
                            frameElement = frameElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.TreeScope_Descendants, conditions);
                if (frameElement != null)
                    return ((IUIAutomationValuePattern)frameElement.GetCurrentPattern(10002)).CurrentValue;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

The COM interface is much more efficient then the old one from System.Windows.Automation.

Comment: What is `CUIAutomation` and `IUIAutomationCondition` and how do you add it/them to a C# project?

Comment: @JasonSnelders Here's a link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview